# Laravel records after a given ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to get 10 records after a given record ID.

```
$media =  Media::where('active', '=', 1)->after('id',$after)->take(10)->get();
```

There is no `after` function in Laravel. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Can you just use a where clause where `$id > $after` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use another [`where` clause](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects):

```
$media =  Media::where('active', 1) // don't need the "="
               ->where('id', '>', $after)
               ->take(10)
               ->get();
```

This will build the following query in SQL (assuming your `$table` is defined as "media" in the Media model):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM media 
 WHERE active = 1 
   AND id > $after 
 LIMIT 10
```

As [@lukasgeiter mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27766908/658210), you should order your results by the id column as the order of results is not guaranteed without an order by statement.

Comment: This works, what if I want to use a custom identifier? `slug` instead of `id`?

Comment: It's just a case of swapping `id` for `slug`. Note - if `slug` is to be the primary key, you need to define that in the model.

Comment: mmm looks like I have to retrieve the record ID first.

Comment: would this work? `where('slug', '>', $after)` ? `slug` is varchar!

Comment: nope, in this case `slug` is a random string. guess I have to retrieve record id first.

Comment: OK.. as a rule, if it works in raw SQL, then you build a query for it in Laravel.  If in doubt, I would recommend testing your query on the DB first, before you try to build it in Laravel.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean `id > $after`?

```
$media =  Media::where('active', '=', 1)
               ->where('id', '>', $after)
               ->take(10)
               ->get();
```

Also to make sure that the result will be ordered by id and you take the first 10 after `$after`:

```
$media =  Media::where('active', '=', 1)
               ->where('id', '>', $after)
               ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
               ->take(10)
               ->get();
```